# Does company-wide require a hyphen, or can you use companywide?

Tags: hyphenation

We use citywide, statewide, and countrywide. Is it OK to say "companywide"? Or does that word need to be hyphenated: company-wide?

The sentence I'm working with begins:

> Provide the same data companywide ...

Comment: [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/company-wide) says that all 3 alternative spellings are acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either is fine but (IMO) *company-wide* will feel more official to the average person, the reason being that since you'll find examples of both usages online, and the group that expects there to be a hyphen may view it as misused, while the group that didn't expect a hyphen but sees one is less likely to think it's misused (IMO).

Basically, including a hyphen has a less of a downside to surprise someone.

Comment: good point I'll edit my answer.